# chart.js legend not working for pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, data-visualization, chart.js

I am writing a small application. I am using chart.js for drawing piecharts.I am able to draw the piechart successfully. But somehow legend is not working. May I know where I am going wrong? My code is as shown below:

**Code:**

```
<body onload = onLoading()>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Test</h3>       
    </div>

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <nav>
            <ul class="control-box pager">
                <li><a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
                <li><a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
       <!-- /.control-box -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail" id="tmp">
                                   <h3>A</h3><canvas id="i1"></canvas>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <h3>B</h3><canvas id="i2"></canvas>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                     <h3>C</h3><canvas id="i3"></canvas>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <h3>D</h3><canvas id="i4"></canvas>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

              </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 

        </div>




    </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

</div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->          

</div><!-- /.container -->


<script type="text/javascript">
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000
    })
  });

  function onLoading()

{          

var pieData = [
   {
      value: 25,
      label: 'Java',
      color: "#F38630"
   },
   {
      value: 10,
      label: 'Scala',
      color: "#F34353",
   },
   {
      value: 30,
      label: 'PHP',
      color: '#B276B2 '
   },
   {
      value : 35,
      label: 'HTML',
      color: '#5DA5DA'
   }
];
var context = document.getElementById('i1').getContext('2d');
var skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(pieData);
document.getElementById('i1').innerHTML = skillsChart.generateLegend();

context = document.getElementById('i2').getContext('2d');
skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(pieData);
document.getElementById('i2').innerHTML = skillsChart.generateLegend();

context = document.getElementById('i3').getContext('2d');
skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(pieData);
document.getElementById('i3').innerHTML = skillsChart.generateLegend();

context = document.getElementById('i4').getContext('2d');
skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(pieData);
document.getElementById('i4').innerHTML = skillsChart.generateLegend();
}

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The legend must be added to an element separate from the canvas element. So what you need is something like

```
...
<h3>A</h3><canvas id="i1"></canvas>
<div id="i1-legend"></div>
...
```

with script

```
document.getElementById('i1-legend').innerHTML = skillsChart.generateLegend();
```

---

Also, you'd probably need CSS to style it right, like so

```
ul.pie-legend {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.pie-legend span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```